# PHP session expires on airtel wifi hotspot. How can I debug this?

Tags: php, session, laminas

This can be a strange error based on a network connection from India. My php session is expiring frequently for the last few days when connected to internet with wifi from Cellular Hotspot. This is felt only when connected to my particular cellular network which is Airtel. Other office wifi based on Asianet Broadband is not throwing this issue. Can some one help me specifying how to debug this particular case. Just access 3 or four links after logging in, and my system logs out for this wifi hotspot.

```
'session_config' => [
    'cookie_lifetime'     => 60*60*1, // Session cookie will expire in 1 hour.
    'gc_maxlifetime'      => 60*60*24*30, // How long to store session data on server (for 1 month).
],
'session_storage' => [
    'type' => SessionArrayStorage::class
],
```

If some one can suggest me a way to debug this issue, it would be a great help

Comment: _..I know that you can't figure out the issue with this bare minimum details...._ Then it makes no sense to ask. However I guess your IP is changing many times. Check this.